# Why does matching enum variants with their names and types not work?

Tags: rust

Consider the following example:

```
pub enum DigitalWallet {
    WithMemo {
        currency: String,
        address: String,
        tag: String,
    },
    WithoutMemo {
        currency: String,
        address: String,
    },
}

impl<'a> DigitalWallet {
    fn getCurrency(self: &'a Self) -> &'a String {
        match self {
            DigitalWallet::WithMemo {
                currency: String, ..
            } => currency,
            DigitalWallet::WithoutMemo {
                currency: String, ..
            } => currency,
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it result in the following?

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `currency` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:18:18
   |
18 |             } => currency,
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `currency` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:21:18
   |
21 |             } => currency,
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Comment: Please always include the **full** error message

Comment: Also you can just do: `getCurrent(&'a self)`

Comment: And you should almost never return `&String` as `&str` is usually enough and more future-proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have got the syntax wrong. Types are *never* repeated in patterns.

The syntax for a field pattern is `field_name: binding_name` (and `field_name: field_name` can be simplified as just `field_name`):

```rust
struct Foo {
    foo: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { foo: 42 };

    match foo {
        Foo {
            foo: local_name_for_that_foo,
        } => {
            println!("{}", local_name_for_that_foo);
        }
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9248b17c16c8de6a747bbc0f20765457))

Therefore you need

```rust
match self {
    DigitalWallet::WithMemo { currency, .. } => currency,
    DigitalWallet::WithoutMemo { currency, .. } => currency,
}
```